# Scope of Cell Object in For Loop - VBA

Tags: vba, scope

I'm working on a bit of VBA that's intended to loop over a Schedule Builder for students made in Excel. I keep getting an Error 424 during the assignments `c = c.Offset(X, 0)`, but only in the nested For loops. Is there a limited scope, and if so, how do I overcome it?

Below is the code:

```
    Public Sub generateRosters()

    Worksheets("Course Rosters").Cells.ClearContents
    Worksheets("Course Rosters").Range("A1") = "Course"
    Worksheets("Course Rosters").Range("B1") = "Room"

    Dim classTitleRange As Range
    Set classTitleRange = Worksheets("Master School Schedule").Range("D1:BN1")

    Dim rowCount As Integer
    rowCount = 2

    Dim periodArr(1 To 8) As String
    periodArr(1) = "A"
    periodArr(2) = "B"
    periodArr(3) = "C"
    periodArr(4) = "D"
    periodArr(5) = "E"
    periodArr(6) = "F"
    periodArr(7) = "G"
    periodArr(8) = "Z"

    For Each c In classTitleRange.Cells

        Dim courseTitle As String
        courseTitle = c

        c = c.Offset(2, 0)

        Dim room As String
        room = c

        For Each p In periodArr()

            Dim offsetCount As Integer
            offsetCount = 0

            For i = 1 To 340
                c = c.Offset(1, 0) '424 Error One
                If c = p Then

                End If
                offsetCount = offsetCount + 1
            Next

            c = c.Offset(-offsetCount, 0) '424 Error Two

        Next

        Worksheets("Course Rosters").Range("A" & rowCount) = "'" & courseTitle
        Worksheets("Course Rosters").Range("B" & rowCount) = room

        rowCount = rowCount + 1

    Next

    End Sub
```

Thanks, for your help.

Edit: Side question, is there a way for me to create a variable that I can manipulate like c, but not be c. Basically a `Dim d As (Something)` followed by `d = c`. I can't seem to find the right object to assign to d, so that I can make it c. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get logic and goal of your code therefore there are only some tips for you:

```
c=c.offset(2,0)
```

changes initial `Range type c variable` into empty or any other value.
Next you try to use, in the line with error, the same `c variable` as range object which is not allowed.

What you possibly need is the `Set instruction` in the following lines:

```
Set c= c.offset(2,0)
'....
Set c= c.offset(1,0)
```

But as I said, I don't know the complete logic therefore this is solution for the error you have but not sure if it solve all your problems.

Comment: My logic is that I'm fairly new to VBA and didn't know any better. Thanks for the help!